# Counting hits by domain

Tags: javascript, array

I wrote this algorithm which takes input data from something like a CSV file or a large array that contain a series of String elements in the format of "count, FQDN" and then adds or increments the count of each domain component up to the complete FQDN. For example:

```
// Sample output (in any order/format):
// getTotalsByDomain(counts)
//   1320    com
//   900    google.com
//   410    yahoo.com
//    60    mail.yahoo.com
//    10    mobile.sports.yahoo.com
//    50    sports.yahoo.com
//    10    stackoverflow.com
//     3  org
//     3  wikipedia.org
//     2  en.wikipedia.org
//     1  es.wikipedia.org
//     1  mobile.sports
//   1  sports

let counts = [ "900,google.com",
    "60,mail.yahoo.com", 
    "10,mobile.sports.yahoo.com", 
    "40,sports.yahoo.com", 
    "300,yahoo.com", 
    "10,stackoverflow.com", 
    "2,en.wikipedia.org", 
    "1,es.wikipedia.org", 
    "1,mobile.sports" ];
```

I was able to do this pretty well with the below algorithm, but I am concerned with the inner for loop which uses var 'j'. I felt like the only way that I could incrementally parse the domain components from the already split array was to create another array which unshifted the domain components to partially create a new array until I completed all of the components of the given FQDN element.

```
function getDomainHits(arr){

  var splitCount = [];
  var domainCountDict = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    splitCount = arr[i].split(",");

    var curCnt = 0;
          if (splitCount[0]){

            curCnt = splitCount[0];

          }

    var domain = [];
    var currentDom = [];
          if (splitCount[1] != undefined && splitCount[1]){

            domain = splitCount[1].split(".");


            for (var j = domain.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){


               currentDom.unshift(domain.pop());

               /*console.log("current iter: " + k + "\n"
                           + "currentDom: " + currentDom.join(".") + "\n"
                           + "current count: " + curCnt + "\n");*/

              if (currentDom.join(".") in domainCountDict){
                /*console.log("currentDom2: " + currentDom.join("."));
                console.log("increment existing");*/
                domainCountDict[currentDom.join(".")] += parseInt(curCnt);  


              }
              if (!(currentDom.join(".") in domainCountDict)){
                /*console.log("currentDom3: " + currentDom.join("."));
                console.log("increment new");*/
                domainCountDict[currentDom.join(".")] = parseInt(curCnt);


                //console.log(domainCountDict);
              }

            }

          }

  }

  return domainCountDict;

}

console.log(getDomainHits(counts));
```

If you want to see a complete walkthrough of my logic then you can see my answer to [my question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132836/increment-counts-of-sites-visited-including-tlds-and-subdomains-outputted-to-jso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the input until there's nothing left of it.  In this example, I've used a regex with `.replace()` to shorten the FQDN.

If you don't like regex, you could instead split the domain name on `.`, then in the loop use `dom.join(".")` to compose the object key, followed by `dom.shift()` to shorten the array.  With the array technique, the loop conditional is `dom.length` (instead of just `dom`).

```
function getDomainHits(arr){
    let total={};
    arr.forEach( row => {
        let [hits, dom] = row.split(",");
        hits=parseInt(hits);
        while ( hits && dom ) { 
            total[dom] = (total[dom] || 0) + hits;
            dom = dom.replace( /^[^.]*\.?/, '' )
        }
    });
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is a very elegant solution. Thanks for that I really do need to learn my regex patterns. I used to be better with them, but I never kept up with it. Do you recommend a resource that I could use to catch back up?

Comment: Start small and spend time dissecting patterns to see what they are doing.  There are [tools like regexbuddy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/free-program-to-create-regular-expressions-with-a-gui) to help with analysis; some people find those helpful, some don't.  It's a handy skill, but in many ways nonessential—the array-split version of this code is only one line longer and uses no regex at all.

Comment: I am still digesting your algorithm in its simplicity. I comprehend everything up until the while loop. Can you give me some commentary on whats going on here?

Comment: First line of while: add hitcount `hits` to counter `total[dom]` where `dom` is the FQDN; Second line: remove first part of FQDN (**aaa.example.com** ⇒ **example.com**), repeat loop for remaining part.  Eventually `dom` will be just the TLD and  when that is removed, there is nothing left, `dom == ""` and the `while` conditional fails, ending the loop.   If `hits` is zero, the loop doesn't need to run at all, so we include `hits` in the conditional.  The `|| 0` part simply initializes the counters if they are unset.

Comment: Oh okay. It seems obvious now. Thanks again!